# Formulario html en xampp accede al archivo PHP desde C:// y no desde localhost

Tags: php, html, xampp

Pues eso tengo un formulario que al momento de pinchar en enviar los datos me redirige a la página de PHP, pero en la url toma la ruta:

> file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/ejercicio1/muestra.php

En lugar de tomar la ruta:

> localhost/ejercicio1/muestra.php

Y por lo tanto no se muestran los datos, lo tengo que escribir manual.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Esta es la pagina html</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "muestra.php" method="post">
    <input type ="text" name="domicilio"/>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>

</body>
</html>



    <?php
print("el domicilio es: ");
print ($_POST['domicilio']);
?>
```

Comment: Porque no agregas tambien lo que contiene **muestra.php**, sería muy util

Comment: Si te redirige a esa ruta es probable que o bien ya vengas de una ruta similar (es decir, has abierto el archivo desde el navegador de archivos y no desde tu ruta localhost) o bien lo tengas escrito así en alguna parte.  Comprueba, cuando estés viendo el formulario, que pone en la url, pues si viendo el formulario ya te pone `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/ejercicio1/formulario` es que lo estás abriendo mal y debes abrirlo desde `locahost/ejercicio1/formulario` para que el servidor web luego interprete correctamente la ruta.

Comment: muchas gracias tenias razon